# Changing the look of hand cursor in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, cursor

Is it possible to change default system's 'hand' cursor with some 'my_cursor.png" file in Flex 3 so whenever user points over button he can see my custom cursor? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these out:

Unofficial:

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-custom-cursor-tutorial
- http://jessewarden.com/2009/01/making-a-cooler-cursor-in-flex.html
- http://www.riacodes.com/flex/create-a-custom-animated-cursor-for-your-flex-app/

Official:

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cursormgr_3.html

I would then tackle the mouseover as follows (Pseudo code):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.managers.CursorManager;

import spark.components.Button;


public class ButtonWithCustomCursor extends Button
{
    [Embed("/cursors/somecursor.png")]
    private var someCursor:Class;

    public function ButtonWithCustomCursor()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMouseOut);
    }

    private function onMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        CursorManager.setCursor(someCursor);
    }

    private function onMouseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
    }
}
```

Every button I'd use in my app would then be an instance of ButtonWithCustomCursor and the behaviour would hence be available on all buttons in my application.

Also, do remember to remove your EventListeners since they could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for answer and useful links! I know how to change a cursor in my app, but I wanted to leave all cursors default except the hand cursor when hovering a button... I hope I do not need to change mouseOver on all my buttons, but to handle it in CSS maybe, or something like that :)

Comment: Yeah but that is not what stackoverflow is intended for. You should investigate before asking a question :)

Comment: Ah, trust me, did try to google it but no matter my query I was always landing on similar pages like yours... But that's not what I am looking for... I'd like to change just cursor which you can see when mouseOver buttons...

Comment: Then just change the cursor via CursorManager onMouseOver?

Comment: "I hope I do not need to change mouseOver on all my buttons, but to handle it in CSS maybe, or something like that :) – errata 1 hour ago " So.... I have lots of buttons in my app and I'd like to avoid adding mouseOver function to each button...

Comment: How I would do it is by creating a base class `ButtonWithCustomCursor extends Button` and in the `mouseOver` change the cursor via `CursorManager`. Every button I'd use in my app would then be an instance of `ButtonWithCustomCursor` and the behaviour would hence be available on all buttons in my application.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a logical object-oriented approach :) Could you post this as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Done, hope it will be helpful